# Accessing JSON objects in PHP Array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, post

I have some JS that is sending a POST request to a PHP controller. The JS code is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'map-controller/coordcontroller.php',
  data: {myData:JSON.stringify(myArray)},
  type: 'post',
  success: function(output) {
    console.log(output);
  }
});
```

On the server side, $_POST["myData"] is as follows:

```
[{"lat":36.8867497490586,"lng":-76.3046246767044},{"lat":36.88671756964517,"lng":-76.30381464958191}]
```

As I understand it, my data resides in a single element array ($_POST["myData"]), containing a series of objects delimited by commas. I have tried json_decode() but I have a feeling it isn't working because my data object is actually an array instead of actual JSON data.

My question: How can I access each object within a loop? Or is my implementation flawed and should I modify my Javascript to send the data differently?

Comment: `json_decode()` would return another array created from the json object, you can simply loop it over using `foreach`, is there anything else to the question ?

Comment: I was using echo instead of var_dump to test for the success of the json_decode(). I have now discovered that the json_decode() does work as expected and I was attempting output it incorrectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var_dump (json_decode($_POST["myData"]));
```

Results in:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
    ["lat"]=>
    float(36.886809817261)
    ["lng"]=>
    float(-76.304672956467)
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
    ["lat"]=>
    float(36.886146919127)
    ["lng"]=>
    float(-76.305075287819)
  }
}
```

My mistake was using echo instead of var_dump to check the decoded object.